# Cheapest way of getting from Tel Aviv to Amman as an Israeli citizen?

Tags: israel, overland, jordan, israeli-citizens, amman

Is it possible for an Israeli citizen to get from Tel Aviv to Amman for less than $400 (cost of a direct round-trip flight)? I see that there is [relatively straightforward](https://web.archive.org/web/20150126065449/http://taylorrecord.com:80/2012/06/27/how-to-get-from-amman-to-tel-aviv-amman-jordan/) border crossing through Allenby Bridge, but it's closed to Israeli passport holders.

[Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/ru/s/Tel-Aviv/Amman) doesn't have a clue either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cheapest way I know is to get a bus from Nazareth all the way to Amman using a company called [Nazarene Tours](http://www.ntours.co.il/). The bus departs almost daily at 8AM and will cost around $20. You will be dropped off around Amman University. A public bus from Tel Aviv to Nazareth will cost you less than $10.

Another company called [Mazada Tours](http://www.mazadatours.com/) has a direct bus from Tel Aviv but the cost is around $90. Not worth it.

If you don't want to take a private bus for some odd reason, you can take a public bus to Bet She'an (around $15), a taxi to the border ($15), then a taxi from the border to Amman ($55+).

Answer (score 4):

If you are not traveling alone you can use a [Taxi](http://www.amman2jerusalem.com/#!taxi-tel-aviv-to-amman/c1n0j), which could run you by my calculation about $250pp.

If you want it even cheaper you can do a more complicated route of [Tel Aviv - Eilat (#393, #394)](http://www.egged.co.il), [Eilat - Aqaba](http://www.frommers.com/destinations/eilat/255405#sthash.brGPxHQ4.dpbs) and finally [Aqaba - Amman](http://www.your-guide-to-aqaba-jordan.com/jett-bus-schedule.html).

Or you can do a straight trip as described on [True Nomads](http://truenomads.com/2013/12/getting-from-tel-aviv-to-amman/), which would all run a lot less then $400 for a flight.

Comment: The $400 I quoted is the cost of a round-trip flight. And it seems that the cheapest overland round-trip connection would cost around $300 :(