# One way trip from Tel Aviv to Petra and more in Jordan?

Tags: israel, jordan

I am planning a short winter vacation in Israel and the (award) flight back I found goes through Amman and so I thought I would visit Petra and perhaps more on the way back cos why not.

So, I will be in Tel Aviv or Jerusalem or something, the whole country is rather small and I would like to get to Petra. I really, really badly do not want to haggle with anyone -- everything I read includes "oh go to the border walk over and take a taxi but don't let them rip you off". Thanks but no thanks. This is non-negotiable, please refrain from answering "it's not so bad" -- I've been to Israel a few times and I can imagine how bad it is across the border. A guide would also be great in Petra. I would perhaps start out on a Friday morning and need to be at the Amman airport Sunday 11am.

So is there a two-day guided tour to Jordan starting from Israel where I can save some money (and time! -- if the tour terminates at an early hour because people need to get back to Israel, not so good) by not coming back? As this is unusual, perhaps part of a three-day trip? Or would an arranged private tour be very expensive? (more than a few hundred dollars is very expensive for this)

Edit: also, if possible, I'd rather not fly to Eilat -- last time I was flying within Israel I got strip searched which in itself wasn't as big a problem as it sounds, but the whole security process took a real long time and time is of essence here. Of course, if that's what it takes, I'll risk it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several tour operators, e.g.:

This one will even organize travel to Eilat (various options) and hotel in Eilat. It's only one day in Petra, though: 
http://www.tourplanisrael.com/?CategoryID=226&ArticleID=1069

This one has two days in Petra, and the tour leaves avbout the same time as the JETT bus to Abdali bus station in Amman:
http://www.petrafromisrael.com/item/petra-tour-2-days-from-eilat

JETT leaves at 16:00. (I remember reading that there might be a different summer timetable, leaving at 17:00.) http://www.jett.com.jo/SubPage.aspx?PageId=230

Organized tours usually bring their own guide, in addition to a local guide.

Petra is rather large, I recommend staying two days. We did the main attractions in the valley and the sacrifice place on day one and the Monastery and further exploring on day two. If you stay for two days, make sure you get a two-day ticket, it is much cheaper than two one-day tickets. If you buy the ticket yourself: there is a rebate if show your hotel reservation.

EDIT:

> The general Abdali bus station is now closed. There is one daily JETT bus from JETT's offices in Abdali to Petra. - http://wikitravel.org/en/Amman

Comment: The tour operator for petrafromisrael seems to be https://www.fun-time.co.il/?tourId=1375

Comment: fun-time didn't forward my information to their Jordanian partner http://www.petramiracle.com/ on Thursday and Friday they don't issue visas at the border. Me and a korean guy in the same situation was sent back to Israel. I bought the Jordan Pass online (I had an Israeli SIM card from Ben Gurion) which is a pass to various attractions including Petra and also a visa. The fun-time driver helped to get it printed at the border station and then we were let in. 3.5hrs ordeal but we didn't actually miss out on anything so [all is well](https://twitter.com/chx/status/685495549596987392) in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest route from Jerusalem to Amman is via the Allenby or King Hussein bridge. If you need a visa to enter Jordan, you won't get it there. Moreover, it is for pedestrians only. I think that's the kind of hassle you want to avoid.

As an alternative, there is a bus from Nazareth to Amman. This bus uses the Jordan River crossing / Sheik Hussein bridge. You will get a visa there. The ride takes 5 hours. Thus you could do it on your own (and perhaps visit Nazareth along the way).

Unfortunately it is difficult to find out the schedules. The bus is operated by a conpany called "Nazarene Tours". They have a website where you can find a phone number and an e-mail adress. Just contact them to arrange your trip. Note that they also have "canned" tours from Israel to Jordan.

=> www.nazarene-tours.com

Also note that the real rip-off in this trip are the border crossing fees. A couple of years ago I paid the equivalent of some 20 EUR to leave Israel and another 40 something EUR to enter Jordan. The bus trip cost approximately 15 EUR as far as I can remember.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/41795/cheapest-way-of-getting-from-tel-aviv-to-amman-as-an-israeli-citizen and has nothing to do with Petra. Amman != Petra.

Comment: Man I was not aware of this answer. And you are asking about Jordan in general. A trip from Amman to Petra is quite straightforward. easier.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a duplicate. There are some overlapping parts.

Comment: But then your question would be a duplicate too ...

Comment: I am not asking a duplicate. What I ask is quite different: I am trying to get to Petra preferably with a guide. Strong preference. Taking a 5 hours bus ride to Amman followed by another 3 or so to Petra is not particularly time efficient either :/